Why does my Express.js server crash when using nodemon, and fail silently with node server.js?
I am developing an Express.js application with PostgreSQL and Passport.js for authentication. When I try to start my server, it crashes or fails to start:

Using nodemon, I get this error:
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


Using node server.js, no error is displayed, but the server does not start, and nothing happens in the terminal.

I have verified that my PostgreSQL database is up and running, and the configuration seems correct. I suspect the issue may be related to middleware setup, database connection, or some silent error I can't see.
Environment

Node.js version: v22.11.0
Express version: 4.21.1
PostgreSQL version: 17
Passport.js version: 0.7.0
bcrypt version: 5.1.1
Operating System: Windows 11

Code
server.js
Here is my main server file (server.js):
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require("dotenv").config();
}

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const passport = require("passport");
const initializePassport = require("./passport-config");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const session = require("express-session");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const path = require("path");
const pgSession = require("connect-pg-simple")(session);

// Database configuration
const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
});

// Test database connection
pool.query("SELECT NOW()", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Database connection failed:", err);
        process.exit(1); // Exit on error
    } else {
        console.log("Database connected:", res.rows[0]);
    }
});

// Initialize Passport.js
initializePassport(
    passport,
    async (email) => {
        const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM public.users WHERE email = $1", [email]);
        return result.rows[0];
    },
    async (id) => {
        const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM public.users WHERE id = $1", [id]);
        return result.rows[0];
    }
);

// Middleware setup
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash());
app.use(session({
    store: new pgSession({ pool: pool, tableName: "session" }),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

// Routes
app.get("/index.html", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});

// Server startup
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on http://localhost:3000");
});

passport-config.js
Here is my Passport.js configuration file:
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
    const authenticateUsers = async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "No user with that email" });
        }

        try {
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Password incorrect" });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return done(e);
        }
    };

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, authenticateUsers));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        const user = await getUserById(id);
        return done(null, user);
    });
}

module.exports = initialize;

What I’ve Tried

Confirmed environment variables in .env file:
DB_USER=postgres
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_PASSWORD=my_password
DB_PORT=5432
SESSION_SECRET=mysecret


Ensured PostgreSQL is running and accessible:
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d mydbv


Added a console.log inside app.listen to check if it runs:
app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("Server running on http://localhost:3000");
    });


Checked for syntax errors and ensured node_modules is up to date.

Verified pgSession with PostgreSQL setup.


What I Expect
When running the server:

npm run devStart (or nodemon server.js) should start the server and show Server running on http://localhost:3000.
node server.js should launch the server without issues.

What Actually Happens

With nodemon, the app crashes immediately with:
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

With node server.js, nothing happens. The terminal is silent, and the server does not start.


Question

How can I debug why my server crashes with nodemon and fails silently with node?
Is there a silent error in my middleware or database connection setup?


Start by removing all the Postgres and Passport parts; just start a simple Express server and get that working. Then add each part in one-by-one and test; find out what breaks the application

FYI mydb and mydbv are not the same value

Also, as far as I can tell, pool.query() does not accept a callback and instead returns a promise

When node server.js exits, what is the exit code? (in bash: echo $?)

Thank you for the feedback, I'll try it and let you know.

There is nothing on echo $? when exit

Thank you guys, deleting Onedrive has solved my problems
